# How to emulate an exact LatLng GPS location in the Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, location

I am trying to emulate an exact LatLng location in the Android emulator.

However, the emulator only provides support to search by an exact address.

How can I provide LatLng coordinates to the emulator without needing the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Maps via a web browser, search using the LatLng coordinates you need to add to the emulator (see the red rectangle).

This will generate a PlusCode (see the green rectangle). Copy this value.

[image]

Open the emulator and open Settings (click the `...` button).

You can then paste the PlusCode into the Google map search bar.

[image]